# Обработка сигналов. Игнорируется обработка повторно пришедших сигналов

Tags: linux, c, signal

Задача такова: из процесса-родителя в процесс-потомок посылаются сигналы `SIGUSR1` и `SIGUSR2` по несколько штук. Но в процессе-потомке почему-то обрабатывается каждый тип сигнала только по одному разу.

Родитель:

```
for(i=0; i<8; ++i){
    if(rand()%2 == 0){
        kill(pid_ch, SIGUSR1);
        printf("send 0\n");
    } else {
        kill(pid_ch, SIGUSR2);
        printf("send 1\n");
    }
}
```

Потомок:

```
void onZero(int sig){
    printf("get 0\n");
}

void onOne(int sig){
    printf("get 1\n");
}

void registerSignal(){
    signal(SIGUSR1, onZero);
    signal(SIGUSR2, onOne);
}
```

При запуске получается что-то типа вот этого:

```
send 0
send 1
send 0
send 1
send 1
send 0
send 0
send 0
get 1
get 0
```

Вопрос: почему из восьми сигналов обработалось только два? Как это исправить?

Comment: А если слать с паузой? Похоже на Вашу проблему: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285414/signal-queuing-in-c

Comment: да, пока сигнал обрабатывается, обработка подобных заблокирована http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/unix_signals.txt.html

Comment: С паузой нельзя, нужно сразу выводить. Следовательно вопрос: как обойти эту проблему без `sleep()` и т.п.?

Comment: В общем случае (без создания какого-то собственного протокола для оповещения "отправителя* сигналов) никак не обойти, поскольку система не поддерживает очередь сигналов.